# How can I evaluate "symbol" and "(symbol 1)" with the same name?

Tags: clojure

I want to get following results when I evaluate `edit-url` and `(edit-url 1)`.

```
edit-url     --> "/articles/:id/edit"
(edit-url 1) --> "/articles/1/edit"
```

Is it possible to define such a Var or something?
Now, I use following function, but I don't want to write `(edit-url)` to get const string.

`(defn edit-url
  ([] "/articles/:id/edit")
  ([id] (str "/articles/" id "/edit")))`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The answer is NO: it is not possible. And if, despite @Igrapenthin's advice, you wish to stick to this function, you had better define it thus: `(defn edit-url ([] (edit-url :id)) ([id] (str "/articles/" id "/edit")))`. It is idiomatic to convey defaults to higher arities. And be *DRY*: Don't Repeat Yourself.

Comment: You could run your code through a little mini-parser (maybe just a regex-replace) that replaces `edit-url` with `(edit-url)` when it's all by itself, and then pass the result to Clojure.  The transformation could be written in Clojure, or in something else.  It's probably better to follow some of the other advice here, though.

Comment: Thanks your suggestion, it's better than mine. @Thumbnail

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If those behaviors are exactly what you want, print-method and tagged literals may be used to imitate them.

```
(defrecord Path [path]
  clojure.lang.IFn
  (invoke [this n]
    (clojure.string/replace path ":id" (str n))))

(defmethod print-method Path [o ^java.io.Writer w]
  (.write w (str "#path\"" (:path o) "\"")))

(set! *data-readers* (assoc *data-readers* 'path ->Path))

(comment

  user=> (def p #path"/articles/:id/edit")
  #'user/p
  user=> p
  #path"/articles/:id/edit"
  user=> (p 1)
  "/articles/1/edit"
  user=>

)
```

Answer (score 1):

`edit-url` will either have the value of an immutable string or function. Not both.

The problem will fade when you write a function with better abstraction that takes a string and a map of keywords to replace with words. It should work like this

`(generate-url "/articles/:id/edit" {:id 1})`

Answer (score 1):

Clojure is a "Lisp 1" which means that is has a single namespace for all symbols, including both data scalars and functions. What you have written shows the functionally of both a string and a function but for a single name, which you can do in Common Lisp but not Clojure (not that a "Lisp 2" has its own inconveniences as well).

In general this type of "problem" is a non issue if you organize your vars better. Why not just make `edit-url` a function with variable arity? Without arguments it returns something, with arguments it returns something else. Really the possibilities are endless, even more so when you consider making a macro instead of a function (not that I'm advocating that).